# How would I have the grid start off from top to bottom

Tags: java

I need to create a grid that a user can generate by adding the rows and columns ( r x c) but I need the grid to be from ascending to descending.

I have created a method that is able to create the grid:

```
static void createGrid(int n, int m){
    int grid[][] = new int[n][m];
    for(int i = grid.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.println();
        for(int j = 0; j < grid.length; j++) {
            grid[i][j] = i * n + j + 1;
            System.out.print(grid[i][j] + "\t");
        }
}}
```

the output right now is from a 3x3:

```
7   8   9   
4   5   6   
1   2   3
```

the expected output should be

```
1   2   3   
4   5   6   
7   8   9
```

Comment: The 2D array should already have the correct elements, you're just iterating backwards over the rows and print them on the go. Try `for( i = 0; i<grid.length; i++)` or just print the grid in a separate loop (where you iterate starting from 0).

Comment: Side note: you state that you have a `r x c` grid, i.e. the number of columns can be different from the number of rows. Thus `j < grid.length` wouldn't work correctly if r != c. Use `j < grid[i].length` instead - or use `i < n` and `j < m` (because those are the lengths of both dimensions).

Comment: Note that I addressed the issues that @Thomas points out.  There was one other change that was needed as well.  Where you're multiplying by `n`, you should be multiplying by `m`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your outer for loop  from :

```
for(int i = grid.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

to :

```
for(int i = 0; i < grid.length ; i++) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Just have your outer loop go in the other direction.  You have some other problems with your code, as pointed out by @Thomas (Thanks Thomas!).  Your code as is only works when the two input values are the same.  Here is the code with the three changes necessary to make it work right to produce non-square grids:

```
static void createGrid(int n, int m){
    int grid[][] = new int[n][m];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println();
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            grid[i][j] = i * m + j + 1;
            System.out.print(grid[i][j] + "\t");
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    createGrid(4, 6);
}
```

Result:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   
7   8   9   10  11  12  
13  14  15  16  17  18  
19  20  21  22  23  24
```

I've been learning Java Streams.  I used this opportunity to try doing this with a Stream in a single line.  This code does the same thing as my first version:

```
static void createGrid(int n, int m) {
    IntStream.range(0, n * m).mapToObj(i -> (i+1) + ((i%m == m-1)? "\n" : "\t")).forEach(System.out::print);
}
```